# Getting rid of the gingerbread icons

Tags: feature-request, design

Could we replace the gingerbread icons (upvote, downvote, star) and use the Holo one.

I propose:

- **Upvote** https://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/res/clipart/icons/navigation_collapse.svg
- **Downvote** https://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/res/clipart/icons/navigation_expand.svg
- **Star off** https://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/res/clipart/icons/rating_not_important.svg
- **Star on** https://android-ui-utils.googlecode.com/hg/asset-studio/dist/res/clipart/icons/rating_important.svg

[image]

Comment: Where is this for? On the Desktop web app? Mobile web app? Android app?